# Use bash to send command to LFTP and then staying in interactive mode

Tags: linux, bash, shell, lftp

Forgive the phrasing; haven't done anything with bash for 15 years.

I am trying to write a shell script that will run and connect to lftp and then execute several commands, specifically:

```
set ftp:ssl-force on
set ftp:ssl-protect-data on
set ssl:verify-certificate no
```

I then want to remain inside lftp so that I can send additional commands (e.g., I don't know what filename I am downloading until I can do an ls on a remote directory).

When I try to write a bash script to pipe commands to lftp, it works but then also immediately quits lftp when it reaches the last line of the script.  Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 3):

Use lftp's `-e` option:

```
lftp -e 'set ftp:ssl-force on; set ftp:ssl-protect-data on; set ssl:verify-certificate no'
```

---

According to lftp's [manual](https://man.cx/lftp):

> - -e *commands*
>   Execute given commands and don't exit.

Comment: Separate commands with semicolons, multiple -e are not supported.

Comment: @lav -- I tried `lftp -e help -e help` but did not noticed only one `help` is printed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

concat stdin after your script

```
cat yourscript /dev/stdin | your_tftp_command
```

cat also accept `-` as special filename argument for stdin

```
cat yourscript - | your_tftp_command
```